# providing list input to splitLayout

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny can receive UI components within lists and displays them sequentially. However, within `splitLayout` I do not want the items to display sequentially but across columns.

```
library(shiny)

my_list = list("aaa", "bbb")

ui <- fluidPage(
  splitLayout(
    my_list,
    "ccc"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the example above the contents of the list ("aaa" and "bbb") appear in one column of `splitLayout`, with the content of the other column being "ccc".

This behavior is useful if you want to bundle UI components together in the same column but not if you want them spread over multiple columns.

What I would like is three columns, one for each of "aaa", "bbb", and "ccc".

I have tried `unlist` it gives errors. It is not practical for me to create the components of `my_list` within `splitLayout` as they are produced dynamically by `lapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `do.call`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  do.call(splitLayout, list("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
)
```